# Is there a way to create a NuGet package that allows for its dependencies to be upgraded?

Tags: c#, nuget, nuget-package

Last year, I created a NuGet package that contained a single DLL and has a single dependency on the DocumentFormat.OpenXml NuGet project version 2.5.0.  Since then, the DocumentFormat.OpenXml has been upgraded.  If someone tries to upgrade DocumentFormat.OpenXml to the latest version, my code will throw the following error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'DocumentFormat.OpenXml, Version=2.5.5631.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its 
dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match 
the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

I've tried setting my project's AutoGenerateBindingRedirects to true and setting the dll's "Specific Version" to false, but neither helps the user of the my NuGet package.  Yes, they could put in a bindingRedirect in their configuration file and manually tell it to use something else or run the PM command (Get-Project –All | Add-BindingRedirect), but I was trying to find a way of automating this so that they user doesn't have to deal with it.

If you go to the NuGet site, they invest a lot of time talking about how to adjust your NuSpec file to allow for different versions, but I cannot find any guidance on how to actually make your code accept multiple versions OR how to create the bindingRedirect for the user automatically.